# _thnn_binary_cross_entropy_forward not supported on CPUType for Long

Tags: nlp, pytorch

```
import torch

import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

class sentimentAnalyser(nn.Module) :
    def __init__(self, vocab_dim, embed_dim, num_filters, FFN_units, dropout_rate, training, batch_size) :
    super(sentimentAnalyser, self).__init__()
    self.sentence_len = 73
    self.embed_dim = embed_dim
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_dim, embed_dim)
    self.bigram = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,
                           out_channels=num_filters,
                           kernel_size=(2, embed_dim))
    self.trigram = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,
                            out_channels=num_filters,
                            kernel_size=(3, embed_dim))
    self.fourgram = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,
                             out_channels=num_filters,
                             kernel_size=(4, embed_dim))

    self.maxpool = lambda x : torch.max(x, dim=-1).values
    self.dense1 = nn.Linear(in_features=num_filters*3,
                           out_features=FFN_units)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout_rate)
    self.dense2 = nn.Linear(in_features=FFN_units,
                           out_features=2)


    def forward(self, x, training) :

        x = self.embedding(x).view((self.batch_size, 1, self.sentence_len, self.embed_dim))
        x1 = torch.squeeze(self.bigram(x))
        x2 = torch.squeeze(self.trigram(x))
        x3 = torch.squeeze(self.fourgram(x))

        x1_maxpool = self.maxpool(x1)
        x2_maxpool = self.maxpool(x2)
        x3_maxpool = self.maxpool(x3)

        concat_x = torch.cat((x1_maxpool, x2_maxpool, x3_maxpool), dim=-1)
        output = self.dense1(concat_x)
        output = F.relu(output)
        if training : output = self.dropout(output)

        output = F.softmax(self.dense2(output)).type(torch.float32)
        return output

x = torch.from_numpy(train_data).type(torch.long)
y = torch.from_numpy(train_labels).type(torch.long)
bs = 64 # batch size is 64
EPOCH = 5
model = sentimentAnalyser(vocab_dim=VOCAB_SIZE,
                     embed_dim=EMB_DIM,
                     num_filters=NUM_FILTERS,
                     FFN_units=FFN_UNITS,
                     dropout_rate=0.2,
                     training=True,
                     batch_size=bs)


loss = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

for epoch in range(EPOCH) : 
    i = 0
    while i < x.shape[0] : 
    inp = x[i : min(i + bs, x.shape[0])]
    out = y[i : min(i + bs, x.shape[0])]
    i = i + bs
    pred_out = model.forward(inp, training=True)
    pred_out = torch.max(pred_out, dim=1).indices
    l = loss(pred_out, out)
    l.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    print(f'Epoch : {epoch}, Loss is {l}')
```

When running this code, I get an error : 
    _thnn_binary_cross_entropy_forward not supported on CPUType for Long

It seems that BCELoss is not defined for tensors of type torch.long, but on the other hand, nn.Embedding 
layer is only defined for torch.long tensors. I have tried to pass the input tensor as long to nn.embedding and then casting it to torch.float32 and other types, but still, it doesn't work.
Please Help!!

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: @MariusJohan No, it's still unsolved.

Comment: I'm just got it to work :) I had to convert the dtype of pred & labels into a double/float64